# Proving discreteness of a finite, open subset

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm taking a course in mathematical structures and it's the first time I have to improve my ability to write proofs. It's fun, but hard!

Given this exercise:

**Let A be a finite open subset of a metric spaces M. Prove that every point in A is an isolated point of M.**

Here's my attempt to prove it:

Given an open set A, it can be represented as a union of open balls. Since A is finite, each point in A can be contained in its own open ball. Since an open ball is an open set, each point in A is isolated in M.

Is it correct, and/or how would you improve it?

Comment: It seems to be correct, however I think you could improve it by elaborating on "since A is finite, each point in A can be contained in its own open ball", perhaps using a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @HehBot I did feel it was a pretty weak statement, I'll look into using a contradiction!

Comment: No need for a contradiction argument. Let $d = \min\{d(x,y) \mid x,y \in A, x\neq y\} >0$  by finiteness. Can you find $r$ (depending on $d$) such that for any $x$ in $A$, $B(x,r) \cap A = \{x\}$?

Comment: I think that the "open" condition is not necessary. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Didier Good idea! That would show that each point is in its own ball, but could you give some hint to the next step in the process of showing such an r exists?

Comment: @E.Papapetros It is, because you need to show that those points are isolated **in $M$**, not in $A$.

Comment: @ola_bandola My hint is to sketch the figure. You'll find obvious candidates

Comment: @Didier yes that looks much better than what I thought of

Comment: @Didier So as long as $r$ is smaller than the shortest distance between two arbitrary points in $A$, the points are isolated! But don't I need to elaborate on the "$\gt 0$ by finiteness"? I mean, what says it's so (never mind it being intuitively true)?

Comment: @ola_bandola Yes. But you'll need more than that afterwards to show that points in $A$ are isolated in $M$. // As for $d$: what can you say about the minimum of a finite number of positive numbers?

Comment: @Didier Hm, I don't see how there's more to show past that point. Regarding the second question: not much, other than that the minimum is always (1) greater than zero, and (2) the least of the given numbers. It really feels like you led me to (1), but both (1) and (2) is true for an infinite number of positive numbers as well!

Comment: @ola_bandola The infimum of an infinite collection of positive (in the sense strictly positive) numbers can be $0$!

Comment: @Didier Ah right! I accidentally thought of the positive naturals. So then the minimum may come close to zero, but never reach it. OH RIGHT! _That's_ why the distance is $ \gt 0$ _by finiteness_! What more is there to show, though?

Comment: @ola_bandola I am writing an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x\in A$, and let us show that $\{x\}$ is open in $M$.

By assumption, $A$ is open in $M$.
Therefore, there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B(x,\varepsilon) \subset A$.

Let $d = \min\{d(x,y) \ \vert\  y \in A \setminus \{x\}\}$.
By finiteness of $A$, $d$ is (strictly) positive.
It has the following property: for all $y \in A \setminus \{x\}$, $y \notin B(x,d)$.

Let $r = \min\{\varepsilon,d\}>0$.
Then by construction:
$B(x,r) \subset A$ and $B(x,r) \cap A = \{x\}$.
Hence:
$$
B(x,r) = B(x,r)\cap A = \{x\},
$$
and thus, $\{x\}$ is open in $M$.
This concludes the proof.

Answer (score 4):

If $x$ is a point in $A$ which is not an isolation point of $M$, then $x$ is a limit point of $M$. Hence, there is an eventually non-constant sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of points in $M$ such that $x_n \to x$ as $n \to \infty$. Since $A$ is open, there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U \subset A$. Since $x_n \to x$, there is an index $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n \geq n_0$, $x_n \in U$. Therefore, the sequence's tail $\{x_n\}_{n = n_0}^\infty$ is entirely contained in $U \subset A$. Thus, $A$ contains infinitely many elements. By contraposition, we are done.

Comment: You did not prove that there is infinitely many points in $A$. You proved that $(x_n)$ takes all its values in $A$ for sufficiently large indexes. You should require $(x_n)$ to take distinct values for that.
Moreover, this is not a proof by contradiction, but by contrapositive: fixing your argument, you end up with "$A$ contains a non-isolated point of $M \implies A$ is infinite", whose contrapositive is exactly the question asked.

Comment: Didier, you are indeed correct that I should have added (and have now) the condition that $\{x_n\}$ is eventually non-constant. This follows from $x$ being a limit point of $M$. To your other point, I think a proof by contraposition works really elegantly here! Thanks.

Comment: Didier: I have also made the correction regarding contraposition. I wrote contradiction by accident. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks all good to me!